# Immutability should throw error but it does not in string

Tags: javascript, string, visual-studio-code, immutability

I am testing immutability of a string and wrote this function that takes in a String.

Since a string is immutable, str[i] below, cannot be assigned to any value.

However, when I run this function, it does not give me an error. Why is that? (as per my study, I believe this line (str[i] ='x' should break the system/stop executing the function and throw an error. But it does not (this is written in VSCode editor)

```
function tuc(str) {
        let res = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
            str[i]='x';
            let c = str[i];
            res.push(c.toUpperCase());
        }
        return res.join("");
    }
```

Comment: That's just the way the language works.

Comment: hmm but it should throw an error in the console/ terminal cos String cannot be looped in for variable assignment. i.e., it can be read, it can be assigned but you cannot have a loop through it for assignment :(

Comment: Well, as you've discovered, that does not happen.

Comment: String's string value is immutable. But other attributes _are!_ JS objects are full of footguns :(

Comment: a lot of things fail silently (or very quietly) in javascript...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression

```
    str[i] = 'x';
```

implicitly creates a String instance from the string primitive. The property *is* set on that object, but the object isn't saved anywhere. Setting the property on the String instance does not affect the primitive string value of `str`.

So in other words

```
    str[i] = 'x';
```

is effectively the same as

```
    (new String(str))[i] = 'x';
```

Because that transient object does successfully get a new property from the assignment, there is no exception to throw.

Note that the construction of an implicit String instance is not a special case in this particular code; even something like

```
    var len = str.length;
```

creates a transient String instance. (Of course a modern JavaScript runtime can generally recognize that it doesn't *really* need a String instance, but that's the concept involved.)

Comment: **Additional note for OP**: It errors as expected if using [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode)

Comment: Thanks that is helpful. When I console.log it, it loops through and logs x, makes sense as it is the Instance value. btw, I have Strict Mode on but that did not provide an error